# Problems playing embedded youtube videos - but only from my own channel

Tags: youtube

I have a page which plays embedded Youtube videos given the Youtube-ID of the videos.

For videos from every other channel that I've tried, it all works fine.

For videos from MY channel, it loads, but then all that can be seen is a spinning circle - no video.

That doesn't make sense - why should my videos be different from everyone else's?

From a video, I got the idea that http vs https might be the problem, so I tried using https for the containing page, and voilà! the video plays.

That problem is - that solution works fine on a test page, but I can't use https on the actual page I want this for (due to fairly obscure reasons).

I tried specifying "src=http://..." in the embed code, to no avail.

Is there some setting for my videos on Youtube that I need to change?
I tried changing from Unlisted to Public, which didn't help.

**UPDATE:** I tested this out using a second Youtube channel I have and it depends on where I'm currently signed in to Youtube.

Channel A playing Channel B's videos? A-OK
Channel B playing Channel A's videos? A-OK
Either one playing its own videos? No dice.

So, it's not any property of the individual video.